# What is the standard height of PCI-e slots in motherboards?

Tags: motherboard, pci-express, dimensions

I am designing a scratch build and am going to be using a riser card for the GPU, but the case I am designing is extremely unforgiving of errors in measurements.
A watercooling fitting will be directly above the PCI-e slot so I need to know how much room for error I have.

The board is the Gigabyte GA-B150N WiFi, if that makes any notable difference?

Comment: Have you.. looked at the specs?

Comment: Yes, all over the place. I can't find anything. I have been searching for an answer for the last hour. I have no modern motherboards accessible to me otherwise I'd measure one. I imagine that they're standardised.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote/vote to close. I think it's a perfectly legitimate question. Unless i'm missing something blindingly obvious? Please elaborate.

Comment: Are you looking for the height of the PCIe connector socket itself?

Comment: Yes, @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007

Comment: @Raystafarian it is not, I am designing the case around this board. I will be buying this board, I just need to know the height of the pci connector. I am not asking for anything outside the superuser guidelines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [spec sheet for a Molex PCIe connector](http://www.molex.com/pdm_docs/sd/877159206_sd.pdf), the rise from the mounting surface to the top of the socket is 11.25mm (max.).

[image]

Feel free to [look up other makes/variations](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/connectors-interconnects/card-edge-connectors-edgeboard-connectors/1441939?k=&pv535=2&pv29=2&FV=fff40016%2Cfff80093&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&quantity=0&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=25) to compare, but it should be standard.

Even better: buy the board you plan on using, and measure the socket height with a caliper.  ;)

Comment: Thank you very much. I am buying the board next month but I was at a point in my design where I couldn't progress without this info. Thanks again.

Comment: Its the case that limits the height not the board.